# How do you 'dislike' an update on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Facebook offers 'Like'/'Unlike', 'Comment', 'Share' options. Is there a way to 'Dislike'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality does not currently exist and, as far as I understand, Facebook is not planning on adding it.

There is, however, [this plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47023/) that can provide the "dislike" feature.

Answer (score 3):

The dislike is just not "Liking" that item. You can express your unsatisfaction in comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Dislike" button on Facebook. But as many has requested for this feature, Facebook introduced new redesign iconic "Like" button in October 2015.

Facebook has globally launched emoji “Reactions”.

Users can still respond to a post or comment with the traditional “Like” button. But now holding down the “Like” button on mobile or hovering over the icon on desktop, gives users an expanded menu allowing them to choose from six different animated emoji “Reactions”: **Like**, **Love**, **Haha**, **Wow**, **Sad** or **Angry**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'Dislike' something on Facebook.  The feature does not exist at this time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official "Dislike" option for Facebook. There is however at least one Firefox [Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47023/) that says 'This addon add a "Dislike" feature on facebook.'